# Get current running directory via ACE library

Tags: ace

Does ACE library has any API to get the current running directory? I tried to use ACE_OS::getcwd(), but unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is `ACE_OS::getcwd` as you mention in your question, it directly calls the POSIX getcwd function.